# Submission paper to a journal with no reply

Tags: journals, paper-submission

I submitted a paper ten day ago, respecting the dead line. Precisely, I submitted the paper two days before the dead line indicated by the Journal on its web site. The Journal had different editions during the years, such as the spring, summer and winter one. The deadline is important only to see your article published on the next edition of the journal. However, from the day I submitted the paper, I still haven't received any answer from the editors. I submitted my paper, as required by e/mail. I didn't get even a confirmitation that the paper was received. Is this normal?

Should I ask about the current status of the paper?

Comment: You write "respecting the deadline". This does not sound like a normal journal submission so is this for a thematic/special issues or what is the background? Please add some more information.

Comment: Hello, The was a deadline to respect for the spring publication of the paper as indicated on their website and I respected it. There isn't due to a  special issue, the journal simply publishes a few editions a years such us the winter, the spring and the summer one. Every time the journal posts the dates on the website. Hope to have made my self clear this time, if not please don't hesitate to ask me more questions, I am new in this field so I apoligize if I am not so clear.

Comment: How far after your submission was the deadline? Also, is there reason for people to care much about which issue will contain their paper (and thus about the deadline)? Also note that you can and should edit your question to contain additional information (instead of posting it as comments).

Comment: Did you ever receive an automated confirmation that your files were uploaded to the system?

Comment: Most journals have a website that let you check the status of the paper.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, the journal has a schedule for considering articles to be published in the next issues. This means that if you miss a (not *the*) deadline, your article will be considered for inclusion in a subsequent issue. No problem there.

You not having heard from them in 10 days does not mean your paper was not received. I assume they received the paper already, but they 're too busy/unprofessional not to send back a confirmation or a thank you email.

Yes, of course you can ask about the status; nothing wrong can come out of that. I would write an email of the form:

```
Dear Editor,
I am writing to inquire about the status of the paper, entitled:
[title]
that I submitted to the [Journal name], on [Date].
I would appreciate if you could confirm that you have received the paper.
Best regards,
[Name]
[Affiliation]
```

Assuming of course that you have checked your spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should always get a confirmation email that your journal, paper, demo, etc. has been received.

Now this happened to me once before where the journal article was submitted on time but due to some automatic pdf renaming, the journal got sent by the system to the wrong editor who just ignored it. Luckily, because this article was an invited one our editor sent us a kind reminder that we didn't make the deadline (since she never got it) and we figured out what happen and resolved the problem.

So as george suggests, just ask about the status of receiving it. A review will take some time...